# How to install python2.6-devel package under CentOs 5

Tags: x86-64, python-2.6, centos5, mysql-python

I need to install mysql-python under python2.6. 
mysql-python package needs python2.6-devel package that depends on the libpython2.6.so.1.0(64bit)
I found on the net some python2.6-devel packages, but can't find libpython2.6
Server architecture is x86_64.

Maybe someone have this lib, or know where i can find it.

Thanks for help)

Comment: I don't know why mysql-python said that it need python-dev packet, but after installing mysql-dev packet mysql-python packet have been installed without any error)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same issue and this wonderful link solved it for me...

http://blog.milford.io/2010/08/new-method-for-installing-python-2-6-4-with-mysql-python-on-centos-5-5/

I followed some of the steps out of order because I was a little antsy and got some interesting error messages.  I couldn't get mysqldb to build, but then I ran yum to install the packages i was supposed to be building and voila, mysqldb now builds and installs.

Let me know if it still doesn't work afterwards.

Comment: Just need to install mysql-dev packet fisrt.

Answer (score 19):

On CentOS 6.2, I solved the problem by finding the right version of the python-devel :

```
yum search python | grep -i devel
```

Then I installed :

```
yum  install python-devel.x86_64
```

And :

```
easy_install psycopg2
```

Comment: Great answer. And `yum search python | grep -i mysql` helped me find the mysql for 2.6.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you don't have to follow all steps in the article http://blog.milford.io/2010/08/new-method-for-installing-python-2-6-4-with-mysql-python-on-centos-5-5/.
Just build python2.6(+) from source will solve the problem, i.e., don't rely on yum.
If you have python26 installed by yum, you can remove it first(and python26-devel too), and re-install python2.6 from source, then setuptools, and finally MySQL-python.

The following link may help:
http://blog.csdn.net/inte_sleeper/archive/2011/06/20/6556103.aspx