# how to install python-devel for 2.6 version?

Tags: python, centos, yum, centos5

i use centos 5.4 ,the default python version is python2.4,so i use the python2.6.2.tar.gz compile a python 2.6 version

and now i want to intstall board review project it need install python-devel package,if i use 
yum install python-devel,it will install the python2.4 relevent version python-devel,

how could i get a python2.6 version devel package install?

Answer (score 12):

If you enable the [EPEL](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL) repo, you can install python 2.6 and the devel headers using yum:

```
# yum install python26
# yum install python26-devel
```

These packages won't then conflict with the python 2.4 ones.

Comment: I got the following output :/ `[root@vc2cmmkb036933n apps]# yum install python26-devel

Loaded plugins: security
Setting up Install Process
No package python26-devel available.
Error: Nothing to do
`

Comment: Sorry, it's a long time since I had a CentOS 5 machine to play with.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it is more system administration than it should be required. Here are some helpful pointers:

1. http://blog.milford.io/2010/08/new-method-for-installing-python-2-6-4-with-mysql-python-on-centos-5-5/
2. [How to install python2.6-devel package under CentOs 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2546676/how-to-install-python2-6-devel-package-under-centos-5)

However, if you are just installing reviewboard software, you can go to http://www.python.org download the package, do a ./configure, make and make altinstall to a local version and then point that interpreter to your reviewboard download's setup.py file.

Comment: First link is broken.