# error of install numpy on linux red hat

Tags: python, linux, numpy, scipy

I am trying to install numpy  from http://www.scipy.org/Download .

by `git clone git://github.com/numpy/numpy.git numpy`

But, when I ran `python setup.py install`

I got:

`SystemError: Cannot compile 'Python.h'. Perhaps you need to install python-dev|python-devel`

Where to get python-dev ?

I tried:

```
$ easy_install python-devel
Searching for python-devel
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/python-devel/
Couldn't find index page for 'python-devel' (maybe misspelled?)
Scanning index of all packages (this may take a while)
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/
No local packages or download links found for python-devel
error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('python-devel')
```

and

```
$ easy_install python-dev
Searching for python-dev
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/python-dev/
Couldn't find index page for 'python-dev' (maybe misspelled?)
Scanning index of all packages (this may take a while)
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/
No local packages or download links found for python-dev
error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('python-dev')
```

Any help will be appreciated.

In order to solve the problem of python-dev, I have installed python2.6 in my local dir.

But, when I used python setup.py install --user to install numpy ,

I got:

$ python setup.py install --user

'import site' failed;

use -v for traceback Traceback (most recent call last): File "setup.py", line 18,

in  import os ImportError:

No module named os

in python2.6

I got: >>> import os Traceback (most recent call last): File "", line 1, in  ImportError: No module named os

Any help will be appreciated. thanks

The following links are not helpful because I do not have root right and cannot use sudo.

[example1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11073695/why-does-installing-numpy-require-python-dev-in-kubuntu-12-04)

[example2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2546676/how-to-install-python2-6-devel-package-under-centos-5)

Comment: What linux distro are you using?

Comment: Can you ask whoever has admin rights (root) to install that package?

Comment: I am not a root user and I cannot use sudo. I have to install it in my local dir.

Answer (score 15):

If you are in Ubuntu(e.g. Ubuntu 12.04), it is very easy,

```
sudo apt-get install python-numpy
```

or you can compile from source through pip(I think on RedHat almost the same):

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev  
sudo apt-get install python-pip  
pip install numpy
```

Comment: OP does not have root access and is on a red hat system (uses `yum` not `apt-get`).

Answer (score 7):

python-dev is not a python module. Actually it's "Header files, a static library and development tools for building Python modules, extending the Python interpreter or embedding Python in applications." You can install it through Synaptic Package Manager,Software Center or yum.

Comment: Would you please tell me how to install python-dev by Synaptic Package Manager,Software Center or yum ? I am not a rot use and I cannot use sudo. I have to install it in m y local dir. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

On CentOS, the python development libraries are under the name python-devel, not python-dev.

Use sudo `yum install python-devel` to install them on your CentOS system.